# combining a range for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in excel, one of the variable is temp (ranges from -3 to 3), the other is wind_speed

for my catplot how to I set the range(temp) for the x axis

```
g = sns.catplot(x="temp", y="wind_speed", data=ieq_data, kind="bar")
```

when I input this code the x axis is showing -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3

I want to combine it to become (-3,-2), (-1), (0), (1), (2,3)

edited:

```
def temp(x):
    if -3 <= x < -2:
        return "(-3,-2)"
    elif -2 <= x < 0:
        return "(-1)"
    elif 0 <= x < 2:
        return "(1)"
    elif 2 <= x <= 3:
        return "(2,3)"
ieq_data["new_Thermal"] = ieq_data.temp.apply(temp)
g = sns.catplot (x="new_Thermal", y="wind_speed", data=ieq_data, kind="bar")
```

Comment: could you please provide proper code

Comment: May be creating an extra column in the data table which will give you the right label may help.

Comment: @najeem may I know how can I add in the extra column without touching my excel, I'm have difficulty grouping them together

Comment: I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be create an extra column like below and use this column as `x`.
You'll have to revisit the categorization in the function. This is as per my understanding of your question.

```py
def grouping_func(val):
    if -3 <= val < -2:
        return "(-3, -2)"
    elif -2 <= val < 0:
        return "(-1)"
    elif 0 <= val < 2:
        return "(1)"
    elif 2 <= val <=3:
        return "(2, 3)"
ieq_data["new_col"] = ieq_data.temp.apply(grouping_func)
g = sns.catplot(x="new_col", y="wind_speed", data=ieq_data, kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly replace the ticks using your arbitrary list.

```
g.set(xticks=my_ticks_list)
```

Comment: it will be hard for me to create a list as the numbers are very big, it will be hard for me to add one by one